# Appending Table using BeautifulSoup, Making it work?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this snippet here: https://pastebin.com/cNviWz4a

The idea is that i clear a table and replace it.

However, when I do it like in the snippet, I get this: https://pastebin.com/raw/6GF7XZck

I tried reading documentation that tells me to do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = open("sample.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
new_div = soup.new_tag('div')
new_div.string="abcdef"
```

But im not understanding it.

How would I append a table and add to it

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new soup and append that to the `<table>`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

original_html = '''
<table>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(original_html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

key = 'FOO'
dictDesc = {'FOO': 'BAR'}

# append new html to <table>
table.append(BeautifulSoup(f'''
<tr style="box-sizing: border-box;">
    <th class="a-span" style="box-sizing: border-box; ">
        <font size="3">{key}</font>
    </th>
    <td class="a-span "
        style="box-sizing: border-box; ">
        <font size="3">{dictDesc[key]}</font>
    </td>
</tr>''', 'html.parser'))

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<table>
 <tr style="box-sizing: border-box;">
  <th class="a-span" style="box-sizing: border-box; ">
   <font size="3">
    FOO
   </font>
  </th>
  <td class="a-span" style="box-sizing: border-box; ">
   <font size="3">
    BAR
   </font>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Robert Make sure that your string doesn´t contain any hidden unicode characters, for example `\xa0` etc.

Comment: @Robert Try to change the `html5lib` to `html.parser`